# Angular.js updating SVG templates in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

A while ago I asked about "[Angular.js rendering SVG templates in directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568226/angular-js-rendering-svg-templates-in-directives)", where I was replacing the DOM nodes that angular makes when rendering templates, with SVG nodes. I got a response that answered it for me, but I realized that I lost all the databindings from angular.

See Plunkr (click update): http://plnkr.co/edit/HjOpqc?p=preview

How do I replace these DOM nodes with SVG nodes, and leave my angular bindings intact? I tried using $compile to make it work (as I've done with regular html), but its just not working.

code:

```
var svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
app.directive('path', ngSvg('path'));
app.directive('g', ngSvg('g'));

function ngSvg(type) {
  return function($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, el, attr) {
        //skip nodes if they are already svg
        if (el[0].namespaceURI === svgNS) {
          return;
        }

        // I would expect the chunk of code below to work,
        // but it does not with ng-repeat

        // var newAttr = {};
        // _.each(el[0].attributes, function(at) {
        //   newAttr[at.nodeName] = at.value;
        // });

        // var path = makeNode(type, el, newAttr);
        // var parent = path.cloneNode(true);

        // $compile(parent)(scope);

        // var children = el.children();
        // $(parent).append(children);

        // $timeout(function() {
        //   el.replaceWith(parent);
        // })


        // this works for rendering, but does not update the svg elements
        // when update is clicked
        $timeout(function() {
          var newAttr = {};
          _.each(el[0].attributes, function(at) {
            newAttr[at.nodeName] = at.value;
          });

          var path = makeNode(type, el, newAttr);
          var parent = path.cloneNode(true);


          var children = el.children();
          $(parent).append(children);
          el.replaceWith(parent);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Create a shape node with the given settings. */
function makeNode(name, element, settings) {
  // var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  var node = document.createElementNS(svgNS, name);
  for (var attribute in settings) {
    var value = settings[attribute];
    if (value !== null && value !== null && !attribute.match(/\$/) &&
      (typeof value !== 'string' || value !== '')) {
      node.setAttribute(attribute, value);
    }
  }
  return node;
}
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this?  Curious as to whether you were able to get this working with Angular 1.3.x since it fixes a lot of SVG issues including defining SVG in the template declaration.

Comment: I did see angular 1.3 solved the svg issues. I've since moved on from this project and have not checked. If you do any work let me know and I'll update the question and/or mark your answer correct.

Comment: @JasonMore I have included an answer regarding your earlier said comments. Can you please let me know if this functionality is what you had been trying to achieve with earlier versions of Angular?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @salniro. Unfortunately I'm not on this project anymore, but did see svg was fully supported now. Thanks for answering the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in Angular 1.3 and here is an implementation of some custom svg directives with the behaviors you would expect from an Angular directive. There is now a special requirement is on the directive declaration as follows `templateNamespace: 'svg'`

Also notice I am overriding some reserved attributes, for example, `x` and `height` in regards to `<rect/>`. To retain more control over these you can leverage `ng-attr` as such `'<rect ng-attr-width="{{ ngWidth }}" />`

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6etLazLy/)

Here is a custom `<rect/>` and `<circle/>`

```
app.directive('ngRect', [function () {
    return {
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        replace: true,
        template: '<rect ng-attr-width="{{ ngWidth }}" ng-attr-height="{{ ngHeight }}" ng-attr-x="{{ ngX }}" ng-attr-y="{{ ngY }}" ng-click="ngRectClick()"/>',
        scope: {
            'ngHeight': '=',
            'ngWidth': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.ngRectClick = function() {
                console.log(elem);
            }
        }
    }
}]);

app.directive('ngCircle', [function () {
    return {
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        replace: true,
        template: '<circle ng-attr-cx="{{ ngCx }}" ng-attr-cy="{{ ngCy }}" ng-attr-r="{{ ngR }}" ng-attr-fill="{{ ngFill }}" ng-click="ngCircleClick()"/>',
        scope: {
            'ngCx': '=',
            'ngCy': '=',
            'ngR': '=',
            'ngFill': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.ngCircleClick = function() {
                console.log(elem);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```