# AngularJS directive does not work for SVG element

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

All:

**[UPDATE]: According to this post: [Angular.js updating SVG templates in directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504438/angular-js-updating-svg-templates-in-directives)**

Not sure if this is the correct solution, but it works:

I update the angular to **1.3.X** and add `templateNamespace: 'svg'`

===================================================================

Right now, I want to test simple D3.js with AngularJS:

My directive is like this:

```
var app = angular.module("vizmods");

app.directive("axis", function(){

    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: "<g></g>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, EL, attrs){
            var d3el = d3.select(EL[0]);
            d3el.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 50)
                .attr("cx", 20)
                .attr("cy", 20)
                .style("fill", "red");
        }
    }; // end of dir return

});
```

My html like:

```
<svg>
    <axis></axis>
</svg>
```

The red circle will not show up.( I check the html structure, the circle structure has been generated. To make sure this SVG structure works, I copy all generated structure and pasted in page, then the copied one can show up.)

And also I test with:

```
var app = angular.module("vizmods");

app.directive("axis", function(){

    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        template: "<div></div>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, EL, attrs){
            var d3el = d3.select(EL[0]);
            d3el.append("button").text("hello");
        }
    }; // end of dir return

});
```

And

```
<axis></axis>
```

Then this can show the button up.

Could anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I think we're going to need a jsfiddle from you. You're sure that the `<circle>` element has an `<svg>` parent or if it has a `<g>` parent that the `<g>` has an `<svg>` parent?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I am sure. Cos I test it with directly pasting the generated SVG structure in page, and that works. I have not used fiddle before, could you show me how to use that?

Comment: Go here: http://jsfiddle.net/ fill it in an provide us links to working or non-working testcases.

Comment: @RobertLongson  I made one  http://codepen.io/kuanslove/pen/VYBYLz?editors=101

Comment: @RobertLongson I find out a way to solve it according to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504438/angular-js-updating-svg-templates-in-directives

Comment: @RobertLongson Two main points(Not sure if they are the points, but it works): [1]. update to 1.3.X angularJS   [2]. add   templateNamespace: 'svg'  to directive