# AngularJS SVG Path directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, directive

Bit of a short question, but wondering why this is happening:

In the example posted below, there are two SVG elements, each containing a directive assigned to a  element. The first directive doesn't use a template, and is the setup I currently use to assign actions to paths.

The second directive is what I was trying to do in order to clean up my code a bit, but it won't be drawn.

I googled a bit around, and read there is a difference between SVG & DOM nodes? But since both ng-repeat's are working, I'm a bit puzzled on what is going on.

Link to plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/cok6O58SOUyaGHG5Jtu5?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4];
  }).directive('svgPathNoReplace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  }
}).directive('svgPathReplace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<path id="1" d="M 85.750001,0 C 38.393651,0 0,39.02444 0,87.15625 c 0,48.13181 38.393651,87.1875 85.750001,87.1875 C 133.10635,174.34375 171.5,135.28806 171.5,87.15625 171.5,39.02444 133.10635,0 85.750001,0 z m 0,1.5 C 132.28206,1.5 170,39.8217 170,87.15625 c 0,47.33455 -37.71794,85.6875 -84.249999,85.6875 C 39.217941,172.84375 1.5,134.4908 1.5,87.15625 1.5,39.8217 39.217941,1.5 85.750001,1.5 z" '+ 
    'style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;"></path>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most current beta (1.3) allows another property on the directive called `type` where you can specify svg content now.

ie.

```
return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    type : 'svg',
    template : '<path></path>'
    link : function (..)
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's super, bunting's answer will probably work, but this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial research was correct -- in AngularJS, templates are rendered as DOM nodes, not SVG nodes. This means the directive's template is rendering your `<path>` tag as a "dummy" non-standard HTML tag that does nothing.

In other words, although HTML normally recognizes `path` nodes as non-standard nodes, it's preconfigured to know how to handle them using SVG. But when HTML sees a non-standard DOM node rendered by the template (which in this example just happens to be named `path`), it doesn't recognize it and therefore does nothing. Think of it as trying to use `<foo></foo>`.

However, this doesn't mean the `ng-repeat` directive won't work on the custom DOM node, since it doesn't care what type of node (i.e., standard or custom) it is repeating.

### [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hS3Kh0lmpAQS4XvpbyiM?p=preview)

The above example solves your problem by manually creating the HTML node using the directive's link function instead of its template key. The helper function creates the `path` node in a way that can be recognized by SVG, which eliminates the need to use a template.

My answer is inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599950/3126107).

Comment: Thanks! Though I don't prefer to put up constructs like this, my current approach works, but wanted to make it more flexible, and with rchawdry's answer it's much easier

Comment: I agree, his answer is the better choice between the two. The only advantage mine provides is if you are limited to the latest _stable_ release or earlier (since 1.3 is still in beta and is unstable).