# Maintaining functionality of Directive SVG-Templates in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm working with HTML SVGs on a SPA.

I've run into an issue with not being able to render SVG elements within the directive template. I believe this is because my directive is a foreign element inside the SVG namespace.

I need a work around to use the functionality of my directive with SVG elements. Either by making an Element-Restricted-Directive legitimate inside SVG tags or dynamically adding my directive as an Attribute-Restricted-Directive, to a SVG element.

I am currently running Angularjs 1 and I am using SVG elements (i.e. rect, ellipse, g) within my Directive Templates.

I found a stack-overflow post that talks about copying and deleting the Directive DOM node and recreating it as an SVG node.
I'm not certain if the controller will still be bound to the new node though.

Link:
[Rendering SVG templates in AngularJS directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568226/rendering-svg-templates-in-angularjs-directives)

Do you have a suggestion to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Using any later version of Angularjs than 1.3.0, in the directive definition object you can declare the `templateNamespace` as `svg`. Then set `replace` to `true`:

```
// ...

.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        template: '<ellipse rx="100" ry="33" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#00ff00" / >',
        replace: true
    }
});
```

This will render the template correctly. If no templateNamspace is declared, html is assumed.

As a side note, `replace` is depreciated but not broken.

The documentation on this is located here, under "templateNameplace":
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile