# How to catch html compile errors from invalid attributes by binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg

I'm quite new to AngularJS.
So I have an SVG which I need to modify from the controller:

```
<svg class="rotate" viewbox="0 0 250 250">
   <path transform="translate(125, 125)" d="{{user.timerAnim}}"/>
</svg>
```

user.timerAnim is populated from the controller in a timeout.
This works, but it throws exceptions to the console, because initially the browser reads the d attribute as invalid, after which AngularJS binds to it and starts working normally.

I had a similar problem before with img tag's src attribute, which had a solution by using ng-src

How do I catch these errors? Is this not a good way to animate an SVG in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I found out you can use ng-attr prefix for any html (and svg) attributes to use bind to angularjs. So this solved the problem:

```
<svg class="rotate" viewbox="0 0 250 250">
   <path transform="translate(125, 125)" ng-attr-d="{{user.timerAnim}}"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of catching an error, that is possibile by a function and getting the d value from it you can achieve this problem with an ng-if like this

```
<svg class="rotate" viewbox="0 0 250 250" ng-if="user && user.timerAnim && user.timerAnim != null">
       <path transform="translate(125, 125)" d="{{user.timerAnim}}"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: @user1094553 is the initial value of user.timerAnim  undefined or different?

Comment: It's set in the controller initially

Comment: @user1094553 ok I understood, try to make as I modified the answer

Comment: nope, I'm still getting the same errors, but less of the same error - the d attribute is still being evaluated somewhere even if I set ng-if="false"

Comment: @user1094553 can you make a live of your example with codesandbox.io or some any other online editor? it looks like that you have other problems

Comment: I've recreated the problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iGSxp5HLPqVv77VE
You can see the pie timer but in the console is the error Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "{{user.timerAnim…

Comment: @user1094553 your problem is with svg and the solution to make work with angularjs is using a library or a solution like this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568226/rendering-svg-templates-in-angularjs-directives/19599950#19599950